# Route not being detected for nested resource in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources

```
# routes.rb
resources :assets, only: [:new, :create, :delete]

# asset.rb
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

# rake routes
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new
       posts GET    /posts(.:format)                       posts#index
             POST   /posts(.:format)                       posts#create
    new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                   posts#new
   edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              posts#edit
        post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#show
             PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
             PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
             DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#destroy
   post_form POST   /post_form(.:format)                   posts#form
        root GET    /                                      posts#index
```

No routes show up for `assets`, though I need to be able to delete them without specifying a post_id, because they can exist without a post at  the moment (necessary in order to be able to upload files and recerence these files in the new post).

The routes `assets#new` and `assets#create` work just fine, but not `assets#destroy` (I get an error saying `DELETE /assets/<id>`is undefined.

Help please! :-)

Comment: My guess would be that this has something to do with `assets` being the name of the directory Rails uses to store images, scripts, and stylesheets. If you really want to use 'assets' for something else you'll probably have to configure Rails to put those assets somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For destroy to work,

Change the line in your route.rb(notice `:destroy` instead of `:delete`)

```
resources :assets, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Comment: You're a god among men!